# How to set or reset password for mysql install to blank

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I want a blank mysql password on my new Ubuntu 16.04 development machine the same as I've had on previous machines.  It plays well with my existing local ruby on rails apps configuration files which use root.

I start with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

then I can use

```
service mysql start
```

and when I use

```
ps aug | grep mysql
```

I see the process running

```
mysql    24618  6.5  1.6 1230276 133536 ?      Ssl  19:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

I stop it with

```
service mysql stop
```

and then I use

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

and in another window I do

```
mysql> 
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = ''
    -> WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I then use

```
sudo kill -9 [pid_of_mysqld_safe]
```

and then

```
service mysql start
```

to start it normally but when I try

```
mysql -u root
```

I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I also tried using an actual string instead of '' for the password but still had the same issue

I've gone through

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html
and
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275033
and
https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/
and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

but they haven't helped, I get the same error.

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysql
```

shows

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-08-24 20:04:49 EDT; 4min 39s ago
  Process: 9018 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9013 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9017 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─9017 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 24 20:04:48 Ubuntu2016 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 24 20:04:49 Ubuntu2016 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Answer (score 1):

try to access to the  mysql server providing a password. So:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and type the 1111 password you previously set